# Speed up ADO's recordset BOF call

Tags: c++, windows, ado

I have some C++ code on Windows that uses plain old ADO (not ADO.NET) to retrieve data from a bunch of SQL Server databases. The code uses forward-only cursors to allow for fire hose cursors for maximum data throughput on queries that produce large Recordsets.

The code that processes the results looks like this, using the #import-generated wrapper for ADO 2.7:

```
ADODB::_RecordsetPtr records("ADODB.Recordset");

records->Open(cmd, _variant_t(static_cast<IDispatch *>(m_DBConnection)), ADODB::adOpenForwardOnly, ADODB::adLockReadOnly, ADODB::adCmdText);

if (!(records->BOF && records->EOF))
{
  ... Loop over the recordset and extract data from each record ...
}
```

Profiling shows that close to 40% of the above loop is spent in the call to BOF and this is having a massive impact on the overall database code's read performance. Because the code uses forward only cursors, it's not possible to check the RecordCount property as it is always -1 when using a forward only cursor.

Is there another way to either check for an empty Recordset that is not using the BOF/EOF check, or a way to speed up this check?

The other alternative that I can think of at the moment is to use one of the other cursor types and check how that will affect data throughput.

Comment: I know you've probably thought of this and tried it already but you might have success by first doing a count query with the same criteria to see if that's faster, although I would certainly doubt it. Or what happens if you use a static cursor so you do have an accurate recordcount?

Comment: I've switched the query mechanism to use a static cursor and using the record count, but it turned out that the forward-only cursor with using BOF & EOF still gives me more throughput, so that's what I'll likely stick with.